How to move a sprite independently of its parent node in Godot C#?
I am trying to make my sprite move/rotate independently of its parent node, so that the hitbox does not follow the sprite. I am trying to make the sprite smoothly sway side to side whilst the player is moving
I created a script called basicAnim.cs to be used for all characters that move, it contains a function called Animate() which gets called whenever a character is moving. I used the Rotate() method to try achieve this but the sprite remains does not sway while in motion.
using Godot;
using System;

public partial class basicAnim : Node2D
{
    public float yDisplacement = 10.0f;
    public float tiltMagnitude = 5.0f;
    public float ySpeed = 4.0f;
    public float tiltSpeed = 2.0f;

    private float yTime = 0.0f;
    private float tiltTime = 0.0f;
    private Godot.Vector2 originalPos;
    private float originalTilt;

    // Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
    public override void _Ready()
    {
        originalPos = GlobalPosition;
        originalTilt = RotationDegrees;
        GD.Print("Original Position: ", originalPos);
        GD.Print("Original Tilt: ", originalTilt);
    }

    public void Animate(double delta)
    {
        // Initialise original position and rotation
 
        // Update times
        yTime += (float)delta * ySpeed;
        tiltTime += (float)delta * tiltSpeed;

        // Apply Y displacement

        // Apply leaning
        float tiltValue = (originalTilt + (MathF.Sin(tiltTime) * tiltMagnitude)); //Calculate degrees to tilt by
        tiltValue = (float)(3.14 / 180.0) * tiltValue; //Convert to radians
        Rotate(tiltValue); 
        GD.Print(RotationDegrees , " : " , (originalTilt + Mathf.Sin(tiltTime) * tiltMagnitude));
    }

    // Allow reset of animation when player idle
    public void ResetAnimation()
    {
        yTime = 0.0f;
        tiltTime = 0.0f;
        GlobalPosition = originalPos;
        RotationDegrees = originalTilt;
    }
}

